# Cannot grab view and set any constraint in the new Constraint Layout editor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to use the **new Constraint Layout Editor in Android Studio** but somehow **I managed to build a layout I cannot edit.**

Some **views are overlapping and I cannot select the one I desire** hence I cannot set any constraint to it.

The **view is the 'green square' I would like to select.** But there are 2 other views in the way.

Can I somehow **'lock' the not used, or already set views like the layers in photoshop or something...?**

Screenshot:

Please advice any help.

[image]

Comment: Change the id of one of the view then change it back to original. Everything will be as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal advice/"answer" to you would be to leave ConstraintLayout alone until it's been properly tested and re-implemented. I have wasted a number of days trying to get it to do what I want. My conclusion is that it's currently so buggy as to be unusable.

Comment: Yeah I share your opinion. Its like a rule in android development that you should always wait 4-8 months before trying a new thing.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to restart android studio and/or invalidate caches.